# Error: could not find libjava.so, Error: could not find Java 2 Runtime Environment

Tags: java, linux, operating-system

I uninstalled java j2sdk1.4.2_12 java on my Linux Server and Install jdk1.6.0_21,
but when I am trying to run any script I am getting following Error

```
Error: could not find libjava.so 
Error: could not find Java 2 Runtime Environment.
```

I already set `classPath` and Path like :

**In vi ~/.bashrc**

```
export JAVA_HOME=/home/java/jdk1.6.0_21/
export PATH=$PATH:/home/java/jdk1.6.0_21/bin
export set CLASSPATH=/usr/java/j2sdk1.4.2_12/lib/mysql-connector-java-5.1.6-bin.jar:    /home/java/jdk1.6.0_21/jre/lib:/root/mis/mod:$CLASSPATH

ulimit -c unlimited
```

**IN  vi ~/.bash_profile**

```
JAVA_HOME=/home/java/jdk1.6.0_21/
PATH=$PATH:$HOME/bin:$HOME/mis/mod:
PATH=/home/java/jdk1.6.0_21/bin:$PATH
CLASSPATH=$CLASSPATH:/home/java/jdk1.6.0_21/lib:.:
export JAVA_HOME
export PATH
export CLASSPATH
unset USERNAME
```

When I run following Commands

**which java**

```
/home/java/jdk1.6.0_21/bin/java
```

**java -version**

```
java version "1.6.0_21"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.6.0_21-b06)
Java HotSpot(TM) Server VM (build 17.0-b16, mixed mode)
```

I am not getting where is the issue.
Can Any one help me ?

Comment: Same problem here but jdk1.8.0_20.

Answer (score 1):

I encounter this issue before. It turns out there are 2 javac program sitting on my machine.
They are in `/usr/bin/javac` and `/bin/javac`. My system used the `/bin/javac` one. The right path for me is `/usr/bin/javac`. Removing `/bin/javac` helped

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same issue, and it disppeared by just shutting down the CentOS VM and then starting again. Then type in javac command again to check.